# How can I read thousands of data from Firestore and be able to filter through them and render them in frontend ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have thousands of data in Firestore under a `collectionGroup`. I want to get all of the data and be able to access them in the frontend/client-side so that I can do some filtering as well if needed (e.g. searching through certain keywords inside of the data). But of course, it is definitely not efficient to pass all thousands of data into the frontend, and have it re-render when we are filtering through the data. How can I efficiently handle this? Note that the data is quite large (maybe could reach 50K or even more not even sure myself), but I can't possibly get all 50K data into my frontend.

What I want to achieve would be something similar to `Gmail` for example. We are able to display all of the data in `Gmail` despite the amount of emails we have. Yes it's more efficient maybe because they are using lazy-loading through pagination or some sort. But the thing that confuses me is how are we able to filter through the data using the search bar for example and still access emails that are even years old. And it is extremely quick.

TL;DR How can I efficiently read thousands of data from Firestore and render them on the Frontend, but at the same time have all of the data ready for filtering purposes.

Comment: Almost every web application does such large dataset computations server-side including gmail. Another option is to use a worker thread to perform filtering but that would mean you'd have download your entire database which is rarely a good practise.

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR How can I efficiently read thousands of data from Firestore and
> render them on the Frontend, but at the same time have all of the data
> ready for filtering purposes.

Use query from firestore to filter out unnecessary data, Offical [blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore) says:

> Queries scale with the size of your result set, not the size of your data set, so you’ll get the same performance fetching 1 result from a set of 100, or 100,000,000.

Also Cloud Firestore doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in documents. So you have to combine with third-party search service see [Full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=algolia)